# How to cancel background sync in service worker?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

How to cancel background sync? For example when we post something when offline, then realize a moment later that it was stupid and stuff and want to delete it when still offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background Sync does not offer you any built-in offline posting capability. Implementing it is on your side. So it's up to you how do you store the requests to be replayed on sync event. And it's up to you how do you cancel it.

The simplest approach I can think of is to store the posted data in a <strike>localStorage (or</strike> IndexedDB<strike>)</strike> and register a sync request. On the sync request, just replay all the stuff saved and clean the storage. In case of cancelling, just clean the particular entry from the storage so that the sync event will not even see it.

Comment: `localStorage` isn't available in service workers so you would have to use `IndexedDB`

Comment: @abraham You're correct, no synchronous APIs in Service Worker, thanks!